# Reserved Word Behavior

Tags: javascript, arrays

While creating a small counter based game, I had an array like this:

```
var status = ["day","dusk","night","dawn"];
```

If I tried to access the first index of the array, I would get:

```
console.log(status[0]); //yields "d"
```

@monners mentioned it might be a reserved word, so I changed the variable name to `xstatus` and it worked fine.

My question is: why would `status[0]` return only the first letter of the first index?

Comment: I get the full "day" see in jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fZbes/

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_status.asp When you set that aray, what you are really doing is this: status = "day,dusk,night,dawn". window.status can not be set to an array. Javascript.

Comment: might be somewhere between init and debug, your code killed the array and convert it in a string? can you debug it just after initialization?

Comment: Perhaps you have another variable named status elsewhere, or your overriding your variable?

Comment: @Jayantha yes because jsfiddle's window doesn't contain status. Try doing it yourself in a Chrome console for example.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.status

Comment: @Gamster: It's because the code in the fiddle is not executed in global scope.

Comment: There are no other variables named status in my code, and it is logged right after initialization.

Comment: Because you are running in another scope, as Felix said. Click the links.

Comment: So we already established that `window.status` is a special variable. It was used to the set the text of the status text of a website, which browsers don't even show anymore nowadays. Obviously that means that the value of that variable can only be a string and that's why any value you assign to it is implicitly converted to a string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're modifying `window.status` which cannot be set to an array:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.status

---

There is some unexplained behaviour in Firefox. While both `status` and `var status` at the global scope provide references to the `window.status` property, `var status` doesn't flatten the array:

```
status = ["meagar"];
console.log(window.status[0]); // 'm'
```

vs

```
var status = ["meagar"];
console.log(window.status[0]); // 'meagar'
```

Comment: So it's converting the array to a string, thus returning the first letter of the string?

Comment: status is the var. not a global there.

Comment: @RubenKazumov Yes, it is. Using `var` only creates a local if you're not at global scope. Using `var status` at global scope just gives you a reference to the existing property of `window`.

Comment: I'am not sure: `var status = status; status = [...];` is not the same.

Comment: @RubenKazumov Err, no, `var status = status` and `status = [...]` are never the same, but `var status = x` and `status = x` are both equivalent to `window.status = x` at the global scope.

Comment: FYI, it turns out that Firefox treats `status` and `var status` differently in global scope: http://jsfiddle.net/PQN2P/. At least I get `d` in the first case and `day` in the second.

Comment: Mmh interesting. I'm using FF 26 on OS X 10.9.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean, sorry. It *behaves* differently, but it's still a reference to `window.status`. Yes, in Firefox, it appears to accept an array, but only when using `var status`. Very odd.

Comment: Ah ok. I could have worded it better :) Very confusing behavior though.

Comment: Good comments, I was very curious as to why this was doing that. Thanks guys!

Comment: @meagar terribly sorry! you are explicitly right! live and learn. perfect example about importance of namespaces!

Comment: @FelixKling This is probably destructuring you're witnessing. Probably a bug.

Answer (score 2):

Because it will be saving your array as a flat string and `d` is the first character (position `0`) of the string.

---

I believe this goes years back into the old Navigator statusbar days (remember those ticker status bars). The status could only output as string --- arrays, when set to string, are flattened and comma-delimited (e.g. `var ar=['foo','bar']; alert(ar);`)

Comment: *"Because it will be saving your array as a flat string"* But why? :)

Comment: @FelixKling I believe this goes years back into the old Navigator statusbar days (remember those ticker status bars).  The status could only output as string --- arrays, when set to string, are flattened and comma-delimited (e.g. `var ar=['foo','bar']; alert(ar)`)

Comment: Yes I know. I think you should make this part of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you do

`status = [...];`

You are essentially writing or better stated, modifying the status variable on the window object.

`window.status = [...];`

If `status` is set as a new variable: `var status = [...]` then this will resolve the issue. I know you have `var` status in your example above but without it is the only way I can think of that would cause the issue.

**Update**

As Felix Kling states, the variable, being defined in a global scope and not encapsulated, will face this issue since it is a member variable on the window object.

I would suggest changing the name of the variable, or encapsulating it.

Comment: That's incorrect. In global scope it doesn't matter whether you use `var` or not.

Comment: He *is* typing `var status`. If he does so at global scope, this will **not** fix his issue.

Comment: try doing it without the var, it does the exact behavior that he described.

Comment: Yes, but so does including `var`.

Comment: No it doesn't jsfiddle.net/fZbes

Comment: Because your are not running the code in global scope: http://jsfiddle.net/ehcc5/. FWIW, it *does* seem to make a difference in Firefox though. In Firefox, using `var` and not using `var` actually yields different results. In Chrome it doesn't make a difference. But if you look at the OP's code, they *are* using `var`, so we can assume that they don't use Firefox.

Comment: Yeah I am seeing what you mean now with the global scope. I didn't know that it would work differently in or out with `var` defined.

Answer (score -1):

You have reassigned the 'status' variable to a string that begins with 'd' (i.e. day, dusk, or dawn).

```
var status = 'day';
console.log(status[0]) // d
console.log(status[1]) // a 
// etc...
```

Strings are treated as arrays of characters so you are accessing the individual characters with the brackets.